# Cannot convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datarow

i am trying to get datarow from aspxgridview but it says

Cannot convert type 'object[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'

code i tried is

```
 DataRow dr = (DataRow)ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(i, "ID", "School ID", "Name", "Type", "DOB", "Cell", "Guardian Cell");
```

&&

```
DataRow dr = (DataRow)ASPxGridView1.GetRow(i);
```

Comment: Tried cast to `DataRowView`? I also suggest to debug your code and inspect that variable to find the correct type.

Comment: it says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to 'System.Data.DataRow'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling [GetDataRow](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_GetDataRowtopic), that will return you a `DataRow` - the methods you are calling just now return `object` (which probably just wrap up `object[]`).